# how to remove space in .htaccess using php

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

This is php code

```
$category = $_GET['category'];
    $model = $_GET['model'];
    //connect to database

         mysql_connect('localhost','user','password');
         mysql_select_db('user');


    $result = mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); //the main trick
    $q=mysql_query("select * from data where category='$category' And model='$model' AND TRIM(model) IS NOT NULL");

    //Adds one to the counter
     mysql_query("UPDATE daata SET counter = counter + 1 where category='$category' And model='$model'");

     //Retreives the current count
     $count = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT counter FROM data"));
    $row=mysql_fetch_object($q);

    echo mysql_error();


    ?>

    <table class='hovertable'><?php if($row->model):?><tr class=\"style1\"><td width='200'><b>Model:</b></td><td><?php echo $row->model ?></td></tr><?php endif; ?>
    <?php if($row->category):?><tr class=\"style1\"><td width='200'><b>Category:</b></td><td><?php echo $row->category?></td></tr><?php endif; ?></table>
```

i am using this .htaccess file

.htaccess

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-([0-9]+)\.html$ detail.php?category=$1&model=$2
```

it is showing like this

```
abc-123.html
```

and suppose i have a space like this

```
abc-123 xyz.html
```

so it it is not working

and it is showing like this

```
abc-123%20xyz.html
```

but no result found

and i want like this if space is found 
then showing like this

```
abc-123-xyz.html
```

and if space is not found then showing like this

```
 abc-123.html
```

so how can i fix this issue

please help me to fix this issue thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to have SEO/User-friendly urls... If that's the case, you must modify the generation of your urls and in case of a space substitute it for a character '-'. I don't understand what has this to do with .htaccess...

However, you don't specify the language, nor any detail how did you get those urls, so I'm afraid this is all help I can provide to your question in its current state.

Comment: so what is the solution?

Comment: @user1796164, modify the process of creating your urls, I've already said it... `How` depends on the programming language you're using, used framework etc..

Comment: ok i am using php get id $category = $_GET['category'];
$model = $_GET['model'];

Comment: @user1796164, that is not an URL-generating method. Update your question with relevant parts of your code, but I believe you should be able to substitute ` ` with `-` in a string. There are so many tutorials out there that will help you, that I somewhat fail to see what exactly is your problem. Sounds more like you got the code from someone else and don't understand what is actually going on...

Answer (score 0):

If you want friendly URL, you are better of just capturing everything to ONE entry point (like index.php) and handling the URL inside the PHP, not on the .htaccess, specially because .htaccess is a lot slower than php.

Here is how I do:

http://www.prescia.net/bb/coding/5-141018-simple_friendly-url